# Paste XML into my IDE and format it

Tags: java, xml, escaping

I have an sample xml file. I want to paste it directly into a Java class. Before I do that, I escape the xml using the tool below. But when I paste the formatted code into my IDE, it pastes as one huge line. I would like it to look like the original formatted and pretty printed XML. Is my goal possible?

http://www.freeformatter.com/java-dotnet-escape.html

```
<note>
     <to>Tove</to>
          <from>Jani</from>
          <heading id="11">Reminder</heading>
     <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Comment: can you please post sample xml file

Comment: Are you using an IDE? You should be able to get it to do the formatting for you

Comment: Eclipse but can use IDEA if that works.

Comment: Don't escape it. Store it in a file in the classpath. Load it at will into a `String` or a `Stream`. Having one massive hard coded `String` seems like a readability and maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need to use a formatter. In Intellij, I just pasted my xml between quotes and it formatted exactly how I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Java doesn't support multiline strings. The closest thing you can do is split the string manually:

```
String paragraph = "Lorem ipsum ad his scripta blandit partiendo, eum fastidii"
    + " accumsan euripidis in, eum liber hendrerit an. Qui ut wisi vocibus"
    + " suscipiantur, quo dicit ridens inciderint id. Quo mundi lobortis"
    + " reformidans eu, legimus senserit definiebas an eos. Eu sit tincidunt"
    + " incorrupte definitionem, vis mutat affert percipit cu, eirmod"
    + " consectetuer signiferumque eu per. In usu latine equidem dolores."
    + " Quo no falli viris intellegam, ut fugit veritus placerat per.";
```

Comment: @heyya99 surely you did, but not in Java.